# "Thank someone for doing something" or "will thank someone to do something"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, reported-speech

[image]

Mary, "John won't like your interfering his business." 
=Mary said that John wouldn't thank me for interfering his business (Indirect speech) (1)

= Mary said that John wouldn't thank me to interfere his business (Indirect speech) (2)

I wonder whether (2) can be used in this case or not.

Comment: You mean **interfering in his business** NOT **inferring in his business**. Best edit your question. The verbs **interfere** (meddle) and **infer** (to assume the meaning of something implied) are quite different.

Comment: I'm sorry but I posted exactly what I saw. Maybe they made mistakes when they printed the exercise.